# I get this WIERD whitespace

Tags: css

I get this WIERD after setting `width: 100vw; height: 100vh;`.
This only happens after setting BOTH width and height to the values above.
I tried running it on chrome and edge, the same result.
(Funny it works fine if you press "Run code snippet").

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <style>
    body {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    #one {
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100vh;
    }

  </style>
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="one" style="background-color: aqua;">Hello</div>
  <div id="two" style="background-color: gold;">World!</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: is that the white gap on the bottom right corner after the gold div your are referring to?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the bottom right corner space. **Scrollbar** is part of **vw** So to fix this problem you have two options.

1. Add the max-width for #one.

   ```
    #one {
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100vh;
      max-width:100%;//add this
    }
   ```
2. Just hide the scrollbar.

   ```
    body{
        overflow: hidden;
    }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

if you look closely. The white gap is exactly the width of the scrollbars..

Scrollbars are included in 100vh.. The easiest way to solve this is to just add

```
 #one {
            width: 100vw;
            height: 100vh;
            max-width: 100%;
            max-height: 100%;
        }
```

I think this gets the expected result :)